# How can I get or see prop value in my other component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mern

Experts am in the learning stage and I wanted to know how can I can get the text input value from the search bar and pass it to my another component where I have an API URL as a search query.

I have seen many videos which use props and I guess that’s the correct way if not wrong to send the data between components. However, I tried to use that but I have an issue. I can not see the props value which I have passed from my nav component (textfiled value) to the product component.

any help how can I do that.

Please if you can provide a source code explanation would be great.

Also please find the relevant code below:

Please see the full code here https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-nightingale-m2mtn?file=/src/App.js

This is the code on my nav component and I want the onchange value to be passed to the product component.

```
const Navbar = () =>{

const[searchText, setSearchText] = useState();

const handleChange = (event) =>{
    setSearchText(event.target.value)
}

return (
    <>
    <div className="nav_main">
        <div className="logo_main">
            <Link exact to='/home' className="logo" > Movie </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="search_main">
        <TextField
            id="input-with-icon-textfield"
            className= "searchTextStyle"
            size= "small"
            placeholder="search"
            variant="standard"
            value = {searchText}
            onChange = {handleChange}
            InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <SearchIcon style={{color:'white'}} />
                        </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                    }}
        />
        </div>
        <div className="nav_menu">
        <NavLink exact activeClassName= "active_link"  to='/home' className="navitems"   > Home  </NavLink>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName= "active_link"  to='/about'className="navitems" > About </NavLink>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName= "active_link"  to = '/products' className="navitems" > Products </NavLink>
        <IconButton className="account_icon">
            <AccountCircleIcon fontSize="small"/>
        </IconButton>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </>
)
};

    export default Navbar;
```

The Product component:

```
const Produts = (props) =>{
    
   
    console.log(props.value);
 return (
        <> 
           <h1>{`http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=Mykey&query=${props.value}`}</h1>
        </>
    )
};
export default Produts;
```

Thanks

Comment: sandbox is fine, but please share relevant code here too.

Comment: Hi @GulamHussain please see the updated post as per your request  I have added the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how are you?

What happens is, it's okay, you are getting the data from de input, but you are not passing it forward to the other component where you want to use that data.

How can you do that?

As they are 'sibling' components, i recommend you to put the **handleChange** and the useState where you are going to save the data in the FATHER component, pass them through props for the component where the user types, and then pass the stored data also via props for the component where you are going to use it.

Let me give you a pratical example of how you can do it:

On the App you handle the state and provide it for the components via props.

```
    function App() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearchText(event.target.value);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <Navbar handleChange={handleChange} searchText={searchText}/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/products" 
        render= { (props) => <Produts {...props} searchText={searchText} /> }
 />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

in the NavBar component you get them via props, destructuring it:

```
const Navbar = ({handleChange, searchText}) => {


  return (
    <>
      <div className="nav_main">
        <div className="logo_main">
          <Link exact to="/home" className="logo">
            {" "}
            Movie{" "}
          </Link>
        </div>
```

and in the Produts component you get them also via props:

```
const Produts = (props) => {
  console.log(props.searchText);

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState([
    // the below is an fake api data which needs to be deleted when final disgn is ready and add real api from useEffect
    {
      adult: false,
```

observe that, before you were getting "props.value" but the name that you get in the component is the same name that you used to pass it from the provider component, in this case 'searchText'.

tl;dr

You need to pass them via props, choosing a name, and you get them from the other side using the same name. To get them you can either use 'props.PROP_NAME' or you can use the destructuring method and get the name directly.
Also, to pass a props through a Router rendered component you have to use this syntax:

render= { (props) => <Produts {...props} PROP_NAME={VARIABLE_YOU_ARE_USING}

On the NavBar and the Produts components i used different methods so you can see that you can use both for getting the props information.

I hope that can help, anyway i'm available for further explanations.

Comment: Hi @Morato_dev thank you so much. Sure will give this a try and get back to you. but just the final question. Is this a best practice to add details into app.js file ? as I have seen people they have only few things in there app.js which is a main part basically. only wanted to for best practice. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. @Morata_dev it did work well. but why did you use to render? does it mean if want to show any value on any component we have to render and then pass the value? Sorry for asking so many questions

Comment: Hello @TapeshPatel. You're correct, the best practice is to let the App.js as clean as possible. What you could do with your architecture is to put a file named **pages** and inside of it a component that would have these components that you're working with. Since you don't have them yet you can put it in the App because that's the father component.

Comment: I'm glad it worked :). We use render here because the component is being rendered inside a **Route** tag. When the component is inside Route tag we can't pass props through without using that render syntax that will make sure to maintain the data when rendering it.

Answer (score 0):

The NavLink has additional properties which can be used.  The 'to' attribute needn't be only a string value.  For example:

`<NavLink exact activeClassName= "active_link"  to = '/products' className="navitems" > Products </NavLink>`

can be rewritten as

```
to={{
   pathName: '/products', 
   someProps:{data: 'Place any Data here'} 
}} 
className="navitems" > Products </NavLink>
```

Then in your products component you should be able to retrieve the data using this.props.location.someProps.data.

Take a look at these articles:
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object,
https://medium.com/@bopaiahmd.mca/how-to-pass-props-using-link-and-navlink-in-react-router-v4-75dc1d9507b4

They outline exactly how this should be used.